# Installing private package from Github Package registry using Yarn fails with not authorized

Tags: registry, yarnpkg, github-package-registry, npm-registry

This question is related to these. But none of the solutions worked for me.

- [Yarn can't find private Github npm registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58316109/yarn-cant-find-private-github-npm-registry)
- [Installing private package from Github Package registry fails with not found/not authorized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58522363/installing-private-package-from-github-package-registry-fails-with-not-found-not)

I can install a package without issues with `npm install @scope/package` however I cannot do the same with yarn: `yarn add @scope/package`

yarn throws the following error:
`An unexpected error occurred: "https://npm.pkg.github.com/download/@scope/package/1.2.8/089b08cffb16074c210ec3a59b04de268ae1c7b3a0492dce110adee3ada05bdd: Request failed \"401 Unauthorized\"".`

my .npmrc file looks like this: (tried with and without below .yarnrc)

```
registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=MY_AUTHTOKEN
@scope:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/
```

I have tried adding this .yarnrc file:

```
registry "https://registry.npmjs.org"
"@scope:registry" "https://npm.pkg.github.com"
```

(without .yarnrc) I've tried this .npmrc file

```
registry=https://registry.yarnpkg.com/

@scope:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com
//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=MY_AUTHTOKEN
always-auth=true
```

Where `MY_AUTHTOKEN` is my `Personal Access Token` I've generated from Github. (it has access to everything in packages)

I have tried to:

- remove yarn.lock
- remove .yarnrc
- login with `npm login` using my PAT as the password
- logout of npm and removing global .npmrc and .yarnrc
- logging in with `yarn login`

In case of any confusion
I'm not actually trying @scope and /package but my actual scope and package name.

I do have access to the scope and package on Github.

and again my first setup works just fine with npm. But I cannot get this working with yarn, and cannot find any valid existing solution on SO.

Comment: You say you solved this with Yarn 2. Could you explain how? It's not clear.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The following worked for me in `.npmrc`

```
@mvce-superstars:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com
```

Using [yarn v2](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/install), the following worked for me in [`.yarnrc.yml`](https://yarnpkg.com/configuration/yarnrc):

```
npmScopes:
  "mvce-superstars":
    npmAlwaysAuth: true
    npmAuthToken: xxx-xxx # optional
    npmRegistryServer: "https://npm.pkg.github.com"
```

#### *Note*

> The scope name is *lowercase*. This is supposed to be the name of the
> owner of the repository (ex. [`MVCE-Superstars`](https://github.com/MVCE-Superstars)) where the package was
> published, but the name has to be all lower-cased.

---

## The setup

### Publishing

- I created a [private copy](https://help.github.com/en/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/duplicating-a-repository) of this [hello-world](https://github.com/rms1000watt/hello-world-npm.git) repository.
- I copied over the above `.npmrc` **OR** `.yarnrc.yml` file into the repoository.
- Next I logged in using the `npm login --registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/` **OR** `yarn npm login --scope=mvce-superstars` command (***skip if [`npmAuthToken`](https://yarnpkg.com/configuration/yarnrc#npmAuthToken) is specified above***)
- I entered my github user name, and my [token](https://github.com/settings/tokens) (with scopes `read:package`, `write:package`, and `repo`) (***skip if `npmAuthToken` is specified above***)
- Finally, I pushed the package to my private repo using `npm publish` **OR** `yarn npm publish`

#### Output

```
npm notice 
npm notice   @mvce-superstars/hello-world-npm@1.1.1
npm notice === Tarball Contents === 
npm notice 16.3kB example.gif   
npm notice 89B    bin.js        
npm notice 175B   lib/index.js  
npm notice 734B   package.json  
npm notice 2.0kB  yarn-error.log
npm notice 570B   Readme.md     
npm notice 167B   init.sh       
npm notice === Tarball Details === 
npm notice name:          @mvce-superstars/hello-world-npm        
npm notice version:       1.1.1                                   
npm notice package size:  14.3 kB                                 
npm notice unpacked size: 20.0 kB                                 
npm notice shasum:        5379c8030fa9c5f57e5baef67f2a8a784ce93361
npm notice integrity:     sha512-FAI/Wuy4gHW8C[...]FINQeIlZ+HDdg==
npm notice total files:   7                                       
npm notice 
+ @mvce-superstars/hello-world-npm@1.1.1
```

### Downloading

- I create a new npm project using `npm init` (`use-hello-world-npm`)
- I copy the above `.npmrc` to the root of the folder
- Next I logout of npm (`npm logout --registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/`) and log back in (`npm login --registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/`), just to be sure
- Finally, I run `yarn` and like it was supposed to, it worked!

#### Output

```
yarn install v1.22.4
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
Done in 0.55s.
```

yarn v2

```
➤ YN0000: ┌ Resolution step
➤ YN0014: │ @mvce-superstars/hello-world-npm@npm:^1.1.1: Only some patterns can be imported from legacy lockfiles (not "https://npm.pkg.github.com/download/@mvce-superstars/hello-world-npm/1.1.1/426126f89734c2c76bfac0342c1de9c95ad003b6e905a7b9f9f745892c86da7a#5379c8030fa9c5f57e5baef67f2a8a784ce93361")
➤ YN0000: └ Completed in 0.55s
➤ YN0000: ┌ Fetch step
➤ YN0013: │ @mvce-superstars/hello-world-npm@npm:1.1.1::__archiveUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fnpm.pkg.github.com%2Fdownload%2F%40mvce-superstars%2Fhello-world-npm%2F1.1.1%2F426126f89734c2c76bfac0342c1de9c95ad003b6e905a7b9f9f745892c86da7a can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from the remote server
➤ YN0000: └ Completed in 1.3s
➤ YN0000: ┌ Link step
➤ YN0031: │ One or more node_modules have been detected and will be removed. This operation may take some time.
➤ YN0000: └ Completed
➤ YN0000: Done with warnings in 1.87s
```

#### Contents of folder after `yarn`

```
.
├── node_modules
│   └── @mvce-superstars
├── package.json
└── yarn.lock
```

And for good measure, I remove it (`yarn remove @mvce-superstars/hello-world-npm`):

```
yarn remove v1.22.4
[1/2] Removing module @mvce-superstars/hello-world-npm...
[2/2] Regenerating lockfile and installing missing dependencies...
success Uninstalled packages.
Done in 0.06s.
```

and add it again (`yarn add @mvce-superstars/hello-world-npm`):

```
yarn add v1.22.4
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
success Saved 1 new dependency.
info Direct dependencies
└─ @mvce-superstars/hello-world-npm@1.1.1
info All dependencies
└─ @mvce-superstars/hello-world-npm@1.1.1
Done in 1.08s.
```

### Sources:

- https://help.github.com/en/packages/using-github-packages-with-your-projects-ecosystem/configuring-npm-for-use-with-github-packages
- https://gemfury.com/help/private-yarn/
- https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/4451

Comment: perhaps, although I highly doubt it.

I was able to solve it with Yarn2, and using the new yarnrc.yml file pretty easily (with no other changes) suggesting that it is a Yarn problem.

However, your answer is absolutely fantastic, and will likely be helpful to others, you clearly put effort into this and testing it, so you definitely deserve the accepted answer to this.

But if this doesn't work for some one else as well. Try upgrading to Yarn 2 :)

Comment: @MLyck Great. I have updated my answer with the results of using yarn v2.

Comment: I couldn't understand this... where's the `authToken`?

Comment: @geoidesic you create the token in Github. See the [link](https://github.com/settings/tokens)

Comment: @smac89 yes, I understand that. I mean that `authToken` doesn't feature in your answer, so how to specify the token value is not clear.

Comment: @geoidesic under _Publishing_, 4th bullet point. The line prior which uses `npm login`, will prompt you for the token

Comment: @smac89 oh.. that's no use for build pipelines

Comment: @geoidesic in that case, see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23460980/how-to-set-npm-credentials-using-npm-login-without-reading-from-stdin

Comment: It simply doesn't work. https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/issues/4810

Comment: @geoidesic it is actually possible to specify the [`authToken`](https://yarnpkg.com/configuration/yarnrc#npmAuthToken), see the updated answer

Answer (score 4):

You need only to use **.npmrc** in the root of your project with this content:

```
//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=GITHUB_PERSONAL_TOKEN
@OWNER:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com
```

Keep in mind that **GITHUB_PERSONAL_TOKEN** needs **read:packages** scope permissions in order to read the packages from your private repo.

Comment: Yarn does not read `.npmrc`. It's looking for `.yarnrc.yml`.

Comment: for yarn classic (v1) it does read .npmrc

Answer (score 3):

I am adding an answer here because after a day of trying different variations of the solutions here and elsewhere, I found that my issue was something else.

My issue was that, while `npm` is not case sensitive with regards to package names, `yarn` ***is*** when it comes to authentication! ‍♂️

So, using the example from [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58522440/3642398):

```
registry=https://registry.yarnpkg.com/

@GITHUB_USERNAME:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com
//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=AUTH_TOKEN
always-auth=true
```

I needed to ensure two things:

1. `@GITHUB_USERNAME` ***needs*** to match the case that you see on github and the name the package was published under. I.e., if your username is Pickle-Rick, you need to put `@Pickle-Rick:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com`, not `@pickle-rick` or `@Pickle-rick`.
2. You need to match this casing in your `package.json` or your `yarn add` command - whichever you are using. For example:

   `"@Pickle-Rick/schwifty": "^1.0.0"` in `package.json` or `yarn add @Pickle-Rick/schwifty`.

I found this solution by digging through `yarn` [github issues](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/8258#issuecomment-701984874).

Comment: **You need to match this casing** thank you for this!! I've been trying for the past hour and was doing everything per the examples I found online, but no one mentioned the casing. NPM works with lowercase even though the username is camelcase

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me using Yarn V1

```
# .npmrc
@vesato:registry=https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/[xx]/packages/npm/
//gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/[xx]/packages/npm/:_authToken=${NPM_TOKEN}
```

And this is what worked after changing to Yarn V2

```yaml
# .yarnrc.yml

nodeLinker: pnp

npmScopes:
  "vesato":
    npmAlwaysAuth: true
    npmRegistryServer: https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/[xx]/packages/npm/
    npmAuthToken: "${NPM_TOKEN}"

yarnPath: .yarn/releases/yarn-3.2.2.cjs
```

Finally use the import as below.

```
import {x} from "@vesato/libraryname"
```

Answer (score 0):

For Gitlab I used:

```
npmScopes:
  "<namespace>":
    npmRegistryServer: "https://<server>/api/v4/packages/npm/"

npmRegistries:
  //<server>/api/v4/packages/npm:
    npmAlwaysAuth: true
    npmAuthToken: ${GITLAB_AUTH_TOKEN}
```

To allow committing the file, it's possible to store the authentication token in an environment variable.